# How to capture iPhone app debug logs

Tags: iphone, terminal, appium

I was researching libimobiledevice to basically capture the specific iPhone app logs. I have tried with the `idevicesyslog` command, but it gives me all the system logs along with my app.

I tried with  `idevicesyslog -d | grep com.example.Example` but does not give me the info I am looking for.

I am interested in the debug logs of my app.

I know there is a way to capture it from the organizer in Xcode but I don't want to do it that way. I am planning to do it programmatically and then integrate with Appium automation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with idevicesyslog -d | grep '"https://ac.XYZ.COM" >& t' write to the file "t" and then clear the file and move on to the next step.

This I was able to achieve but the only issue I am facing here is that I need to update the command, like it wont write to log on real time basis when I am interacting with the device. If someone can suggest a way where it log to the file in a real time that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use -m option from idevicesyslog, this option is for "only print messages that contain STRING"

Example:

```
idevicesyslog -m "Vantage"
```

Hope this method is work for you :)